# Uniqueness of name in cryptography

Tags: cryptography

If I publish my public key (I think I understand how this works, I'm still learning encryption) and I have a common name, could this leas to problems at all? OR does the email part guarantee that this will work fine? Does this not make it extremely easy for someone to compromise my identity?

In retrospect, this seems like an extremely stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but I'm going to make some assumptions... I'm assuming your taking about PGP encryption and sharing your public key. Let's say your name is "John Smith", now just doing a quick search on John Smith comes up with hundreds of results so lets look at two I picked at random[1] let's call them `John Smith A`[0xA414B7C7](http://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?search=0xA414B7C7) and `John Smith B`[0xB82A4EAA](http://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?search=0xB82A4EAA)

Let's say you are John Smith A. If I understand your question correctly you are asking if there is a chance that John Smith B could send a file and because it's PGP signed/encrypted someone thinks it's from you?

PGP protects against this allowing people to [Sign](http://www.pgp.net/pgpnet/pgp-faq/pgp-faq-key-signatures.html) keys. Your friends could sign your key to say this really is John Smith A. Similarly the person your sending the file to could download your public key and then they could check the key used to encrypt / sign the file matches the key they expect and is not some other John Smith.

You could also use some Out-of-band method to send someone your key's finger print (like printing it an mailing it to them) so that even if J. Random Hacker created a key and said his email was the same as yours it wouldn't match because your keys fingerprint would be different to his.

Decrypting a file that was encrypted with a key you don't trust should give you a warning message.

---

[1] Ok, to be fair it wasn't truly random, I picked them because their finger prints started with A and B but I don't know who they are.

Comment: More complex things I don't quite grasp yet, but a good answer.

So the key fingerprint `0xA414B7C7` is guaranteed to be unique and will be the same for me always?

I could just walk up to the recipient of my message and say "MY key fingerprint is `0xA414B7C7`" and they would be ale to use that to confirm any messages I sent them were actually sent by me?

Comment: That's correct, generally you use a larger fingerprint because someone could potentially generate a key with the same last few characters. What I've posted is the last few characters which in this case are enough but the full fingerprint for that key is `7A89 07E5 CF46 1B7B AC16  CDAC 962F C490 *A414 B7C7*`

Comment: Ah, okay. I really do need to learn some more about encryption, even though it really isn't useful to me right now.

So the only thing I don't share with others is my private key?
Public key, fingerprint...both can be thrown out to whoever?

Comment: Yes keep your private key private, but you can post your Public Key anywhere. Many people post them online on key-servers like http://pgp.mit.edu and then the fingerprint is a shorter bit that you can hand to your friends (or anyone) so they can find your key and know they downloaded the right John Smith from the key server. Many people have their fingerprint in their email signature and share it with everyone.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe in the future as I find uses for cryptography, I'll use and learn more about it.

So much to learn about computers, only one lifetime to do it in. I better get going!